# Not able to update last published date after publishing

Tags: content-delivery, cache

I have successfully updated the page and after publishing the page successfully, still in page view source the page's last published date isn't updating. I have already cleared the cache, still there is the same issue.

Comment: Clearing the browser cache does you no good if the item is cached on the CD side. What kind of app do you have on the presentation side? Am asking because DXA 2.0 has a timed based caching (if not disabled) which is not invalidated by the Deployer cache invalidation messages.

Answer (score 1):

It is most probably cache issue on Content Delivery side. To verify that page is correctly published, please check its content on delivery side (on file system or in database). If all is ok, please restart CD apps. It will most probably fix the issue.

Also you should check why page got cached in the first place.

Comment: If it is cache, check for how long it caches the content... it should show the new version _at some point_ without the need to restart the content services